# Approval workflows in Azure API Manager

Tags: azure-api-management

I have 2 questions related to $subject.

1) Can I configure and approval process for API product publishing task?

2) Can I configure an approval process for user sign ups in developer portal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. This can be done outside of APIM utilizing its Git support, some more information here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit. Basic idea is to organize approval process for developers to merge into master branch. And then deploy APIM config from there.
2. See Delegation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation